# Font issue in Arch Linux in java based applications

Tags: java, linux, fonts, archlinux, arch

Whenever I try to run any Java based application in arch Linux, The fonts just look ugly, I can handle ugly fonts, but the issue is they are badly configured, there are no spaces in between words. Plus when I visit some sites, the source code is just in weird font.

I have tried almost everything I could find on internet.

This is my first arch installation. I am used to Debian, where I never had such issues.

Help,
Thanks for help in advance. 
Peace.

[This is screenshot of Burp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKNAS.png)

[This is screenshot of source code of a website which looks i donno what](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCBbk.png)

[This is screenshot of ZAP, another Java based program.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqnJH.png)

Comment: Review the ArchLinux configuration related to the font rendering, ArchLinux is elegant :)

Comment: I tried that, Cant get anything to work, :(

Comment: I saw the image, the rendering not good, I think related to the configuration. what desktop environment do you have?

Comment: I am using Awesome window manager.

Comment: This issue is with only java based applications, and in web browsers.

Comment: Hmm, I used Xface was really good, you can ask this question in `Linux & Unix` forum also

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: I mean this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oh, Okay, will do that.